# Does Stack Overflow have a public list of issues it wants to address?

Tags: discussion

Meta is great , but I'm really curious how the product management side of Stack Overflow interacts with this site.

Someone comes on meta and says "XYZ is a problem", but I'm sure you guys working for Stack Overflow  have your own list of priorities.

But are these priorities kept in-house? Are there laws requiring that?

I'm curious whether the "Meta" system would be more efficient if there was a controlled way to contribute, rather than via what are often ill-conceived feature-requests. But that makes the users submitting them a bit naive then, perhaps.

Comment: "Public" as in, visible for the entire community? Then no.

Comment: @Bart - ok understood, thanks !

Comment: [public list of issues](http://meta.stackexchange.com/users), sorted from most to least severe.

Answer (score 5):

Anything tagged [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) OR [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) and **NOT** tagged [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined) and **NOT** tagged [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) is something that *could* be implemented.

*for some value of "could"*

> https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/feature-request+-status-declined+-status-completed

These are all the feature requests that haven't been explicitly declined, but haven't been implemented yet, so there's a *chance* that they could be implemented.

Comment: Also, status-declined need not be the absolute final word, though it mostly is (Sometimes things get done after an appeal and some years).

Comment: I'm guessing there is also an internal list of things. In terms of issues, [bug] is normally a good place to look too.

Answer (score 4):

All of the questions tagged [status-planned](/questions/tagged/status-planned) are features that SE has planned to release.